# How to use Font Awesome (6.5.1) icons with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontawesome, fontawesome5

I have to use a `Font Awesome 6.5.1` icon which doesn't exist in `Font Awesome 5` and, therefore, I cannot use the `fontawesome5` package.

With `LuaLaTeX`, is it possible to use and, if so, how can I use a particular `Font Awesome 6.5.1` icon with one of the `Font Awesome 6 Brands-Regular-400.otf`, `Font Awesome 6 Free-Regular-400.otf` and `Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf` files [freely provided by `Font Awesome` for the desktop](https://fontawesome.com/download)?

Comment: just use `\newfontfamily\faSIX{theotffont.otf}` then you can use `{\faSIX\symbol{"whateverhex}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks but, while `fc-list | rg Awesome` returns, among others
`/usr/share/fonts/drakfont/otf/Font-Awesome-6-Free-Regular-400.otf: Font Awesome 6 Free,Font Awesome 6 Free Regular:style=Regular` but, with `\newfontfamily\faSIX{Font-Awesome-6-Free-Regular-400.otf}` and `{\faSIX\symbol{"e546}}`, a `lualatex` runs returns “! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
e
l.51 {\faSIX\symbol{"e546}”

Comment: hex numbers need to be capital with `"` as in classic tex (luatex doesn't use fontconfig) use `E` not `e`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `fontspec` and

```
\newfontfamily\faSIX{theotffont.otf}
```

then you can use `{\faSIX\symbol{"whateverhex}}`  (hex numbers have to be uppercase, you could also use decimal (no `"`) or `^^^^hex` (lowercase) or just type the character directly.